# Unexpected block statement ESLint

Tags: eslint

I have a multiline code still I m getting following error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Message of the error seems to be pretty clear. If the only statement you have inside arrow function body is `return`, you don't need block statement, and can use short form:

```
const Teams = () => (
    <View .....
);
```

Btw, in Atom, clicking on the name of the rule in the error message will take you directly to the rule documentation, that usually clearly explains what this rule does and provides a bunch of samples.